# How can I add more parts to my already complex captain?

Tags: spore, spore-galactic-adventures

I've unlocked some captain parts, but can only equip some of them before my captain's complexity meter maxes out. Is there any way for me to equip my captain with all these awesome things for which I've suffered through many a glitchy adventure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the complexity meter for equipment still has to include the complexity of the captain's species, so having a very complex base creature will leave you with less room for cool equipment.

You can reduce the complexity of a creature by making middle parts asymmetric and removing one of them. When you buy pieces normally you pay for two of them, even if you only see one because it's aligned to the middle of the creature. Even if you can't get to edit your creature, you might be able to place equipment asymmetrically in such a way that you can benefit from more pieces.

You could also try looking for mods or a trainer to remove complexity limits, but creatures beyond complexity won't be shared to the Sporepedia, and might not occur in your games unless it's your active species.

To outfit a captain with all unlocked parts, open him in the editor via the Sporepedia (open it from the main menu) and enter the `freedom on` cheat in the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open console). The captain will continue to work properly if you play adventures during the Space stage, but you won't be able to choose him when starting an adventure from the main menu. You can simply remove any pieces that go over the limit to restore the ability to select that captain when playing adventures from the main menu.

Comment: That mod didn't do anything as far as I could tell, but making parts asymmetric did help a bit, unfortunately I still won't be able to put 10 parts on.

Comment: @kotekzot Fair enough, I'm not currently able to test for myself. I'll remove the link to that and leave it as a generic comment. I know there's a cheat code "freedom" to remove the complexity limit, but I think that only works with the editor modes outside of gameplay and you can't use them in-game if they're over the limit. Glad the asymmetry did something. Maybe look up Spore Mega Trainer - claims to remove complexity limits, but I don't know if you need a separate version for Galactic Adventures.

Answer (score 1):

Once a species has evolved to tribal, you can no longer edit its base complexity. This complexity carries through the rest of the game, so highly complex creatures have little room for space adventure parts.

The tribal and civilization items added to a species counts against the space adventures complexity as well. I've found that by removing these tribal or civilized items (whose only purpose in space age is decorative) I can often make room (reduce the complexity meter) and allow my space captain another item or two.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into your gallery of creations and edit your current in-game creation and remove parts so you have more complexity meter, then save it. If it asks if you want to save it new, you have to press Replace.

Comment: You can't remove parts from creatures that are past the Creature Stage.